# Interpret TimeStamp

Tags: html, json

I am trying to interpret a series of numbers that are representing time so that I can change them in the near future to different numbers. 
How long is 135671800? And what does each mean? Is it DD:HH:MM:SS?

```
{"next_timestamp":1356751800,"next_duration":9000,"next_title":"Saturday Night","next_description":"Hearing and Healing"}
```

The original javascript that is interpreting the result is:

```
else if (typeof data.next_timestamp !== "undefined") {
        seconds_till = data.next_timestamp - (new Date().getTime() / 1000);
        days = Math.floor((seconds_till % 31536000) / 86400);
        hours = Math.floor((seconds_till % 86400) / 3600);
        minutes = Math.floor((seconds_till % 3600) / 60);
        seconds = Math.floor(seconds_till % 60);
        return intervalId = setInterval(function() {
          if (--seconds < 0) {
            seconds = 59;
            if (--minutes < 0) {
              minutes = 59;
              if (--hours < 0) {
                hours = 23;
                  if (--days < 0) {
                days = 365;
                }
              }
            }
          }
```

Thanks!

Comment: I believe it's usually seconds from the epoch.

Comment: According to the code it is seconds since some fixed time in the past. But is is the same point in the past that browsers use. The key is the code `(new Date()).getTime()` which returns in javascript the elapsed time in milliseconds since that time. It gets divided by 1000 to turn it into seconds and then subtracted from your time value which would need to have the same units ... seconds.

Comment: I think you are right. But what is the fixed time in the past? I cannot figure out how to find it anywhere in my code. It is a countdown timer, and it all works, but the time in the past is where I am having trouble, I don't know what to set for the numbers to make it a specific day in the future.

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with a standard timestamp you can just use the Javascript Date object.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

```
var date = new Date(/* timestamp * 1000 here */);
var day = date.getDay();
var month = date.getMonth();
var year = date.getFullYear();
```

Not sure what your interval is for but if you want to count this back down to 0...

```
// Assume that date still exists.
time = date.getTime() / 1000;
time--;
date = new Date(time * 1000);
day = date.getDay();
month = date.getMonth();
year = date.getFullYear();
```

Answer (score 0):

It is seconds from "epoch" (seconds that have elapsed since midnight Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), 1 January 1970).
Actually Sat, 29 Dec 2012 03:30:00 GMT

See live counter here
http://www.epochconverter.com/

More about UNIX Time http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time